# imacro Eval function

Tags: javascript, eval, extract, imacros

I have a problem with eval imacro function.
iMacros for FF v9.0.3 Firefox 50.1.0 Windows 10

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=CLASS:content&&TXT:* EXTRACT = HTM
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.split(' ')[1];")
```

This script extract second word from HTM. But I need to replace = with :
I found that is a `{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace('=',':')` but I dont know how to merge this in one like this

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.split(' ')[1];\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.replace('=',':');")
```

When I put script like this I get full text from HTM with changed = in :. And I need only second word from HTM with changed = in :
Can someone help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just missed a small thing:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=CLASS:content&&TXT:* EXTRACT=HTM
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s = \"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s = s.split(' ')[1]; s.replace('=', ':');")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your script works perfectly. Thanks again